# Question involving trigonometrical equation and intersection of the sets

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

$$A:=\left  \{  \theta:2\cos^{2}\theta +\sin\theta\leq 2 \right \} $$
$$B:=\left  \{  \theta:\frac  {\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi }{2} \right \} $$. Find$$A\bigcap B$$

Breaking the inequalities, from $$2\sin\theta -1≥0$$ we get $$\frac{\pi}{6}≤\theta≤\frac{5\pi}{6}$$ and from $$\sin\theta≥0$$ we get $$\frac{\pi}{2}≤\theta≤\frac{3\pi}{2}$$. If we draw this set A and B we find the intersection is between $$\pi/2$$ and $$5\pi/6$$ but answer says it's π/2 to 5π/6 OR π to 3π/2

Comment: As the upper bound of B is mentioned, I haven't Considered the general cases for powers of n greater than 1, which is why 5π/6  and 3π/2

Comment: Note that $\sin z < 0$ for $\pi < z < 3\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake happened in solving a product inequality (so to speak): "$ab\ge0$" is **NOT** equivalent to "$a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$". The product of two numbers is positive whenever either both are positive or both are negative (you see, not only when both are positive). So once you (correctly!) obtained
$$\sin\theta(2\sin\theta-1)\ge0,$$
you needed to set up and solve two cases:
$$\left\{\begin{align} \sin\theta&\ge0 \\ 2\sin\theta-1&\ge0 \end{align}\right.$$
or
$$ \left\{\begin{align} \sin\theta&\le0 \\ 2\sin\theta-1&\le0 \end{align}\right.$$
After you find the solutions to both cases and intersect them with $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{3\pi}{2}$, you'll have the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
2\cos^{2}(\theta) + \sin(\theta) \leq 2 \Leftrightarrow 2[1-\sin^{2}(\theta)] + \sin(\theta) \leq 2\Leftrightarrow 2\sin^{2}(\theta) - \sin(\theta) \geq 0
\end{align*}